# RuntimeError: b'no arguments in initialization list' with pyproj geopandas

Tags: python-3.x, geopandas, pyproj

I'm running into an issue that seems to share with many posts. I have tried a couple of solutions:

1. conda uninstall pyproj and then pip install pyproj
2. edited the pyproj_datadir

But I'm still getting the same error. The answer to this post ([GeoPandas .to_crs running into errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57285978/geopandas-to-crs-running-into-errors)) is something I would like to try. But I'm seeing in both folders, one with epsg.wkt and the other with epsg. Does anyone know which folder I should be pointing to?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: create new environment, install everything via conda from the conda-forge channel

Comment: Thank you Paul. Can you clarify a bit more about creating new environment? I'm not too familiar with the back-end/computer science part.

Comment: `conda create --name=gis python=3.8 geopandas rasterio descartes pyoroj notebook` and then follow the instructions from there

Comment: Thank you so much Paul! I ended up manually creating a variable path GDAL_DATA, just testing it now and got this message: 

Can't load requested DLL: C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdalplugins\gdal_KEA.dll
127: The specified procedure could not be found. 

I want to try debugging this one a bit more, but I will also test your solution!